# PHP PECL Sphinx module won't install

Tags: debian, php, pecl, sphinx

I'm trying to install the PHP Sphinx client (PHP 5.6) on my Debian 7 server using PECL. I get the misleading error "wrong libsphinxclient version or lib not found" when trying to build, even though I've already installed Sphinx and can see the library in /usr/lib.

```
# pecl install sphinx
downloading sphinx-1.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download sphinx-1.3.2.tgz (15,282 bytes)
.....done: 15,282 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
Please provide the installation prefix of libsphinxclient [autodetect] :
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootAWbWVD/sphinx-1.3.2
running: /tmp/pear/temp/sphinx/configure --with-sphinx
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for sphinx support... yes, shared
checking for libsphinxclient headers in default path... found in /usr/local
checking for sphinx_create in -lsphinxclient... no
configure: error: wrong libsphinxclient version or lib not found
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/sphinx/configure --with-sphinx' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx is missing a required dependency, and the configure script is misinterpreting the reason for the failure. Installing the correct version of glibc fixed the issue.

I'm posting this because there were no relevant Google hits for the error message I was receiving.

I used the following procedure to identify the problem:

```
~# pecl download sphinx
downloading sphinx-1.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download sphinx-1.3.2.tgz (15,282 bytes)
.....done: 15,282 bytes
File /root/MP/sphinx-1.3.2.tgz downloaded
~# tar -xf sphinx-1.3.2.tgz
~# cd sphinx-1.3.2/
~/sphinx-1.3.2# phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
~/sphinx-1.3.2# ./configure
[... same output as above ...]
~/sphinx-1.3.2# less config.log
[...]
configure:4059: checking for sphinx_create in -lsphinxclient
configure:4084: cc -o conftest -g -O2  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -lm conftest.c -lsphinxclient   >&5
/usr/local/lib/libsphinxclient.so: undefined reference to `__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
/usr/local/lib/libsphinxclient.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a the same problem and this works for me in Ubuntu 14.04 trusty

First you need to install sphinxsearch

```
sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch sphinxbase-utils libsphinxbase-dev
```

Then go to the api libsphinxclient folder and install

```
cd /usr/share/sphinxsearch/api/libsphinxclient
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then you can install sphinx client using pecl

```
sudo pecl install sphinx
```

Remember after install you need to add extension=sphinx.so to the php.ini file and restart apache server